# When and where did Elizabeth Swann learn to swordfight?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-mans-chest

In the second Pirates of the Caribbean movie, Elizabeth gets a lot more sword fighting action. (As I recall, she didn't actually get to sword fight in the first one, and Keira Knightley asked for more action to be written in for her character).

I assume Will might have taught her, but do any of the movies explain when and where she learned to sword fight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only explanation is given in the second film, *[Dead Man's Chest](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Pirates_of_the_Caribbean:_Dead_Man%27s_Chest)*. In it, this [exchange](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Pirates-of-the-Caribbean-Dead-Man%27s-Chest.html) takes place between Elizabeth and Jack:

> **ELIZABETH SWANN**
>    Jack, the Letters, give them back.
>
> **JACK SPARROW**
>    No. Persuade me.
>
> **ELIZABETH SWANN**
>    You do know Will taught me how handle 
>                a sword.
>
> **JACK SPARROW**
>                As I said... Persuade me.

Unfortunately, that's all we really hear about her training. The next thing we know, she's a duel-wielding, swash-buckling, accomplished fighter.

For what it's worth, [Cracked.com](http://www.cracked.com/article_18827_the-6-most-inexplicable-skills-displayed-in-action-movies_p2.html) named *her entire character* as the *second most inexplicably skilled person in an action movie.